# change starting value for geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a plot that includes data from two different scales. So far, I've plotted both variables and adjusted the scale of one variable (ss) so that it is closer to the other variables. This greatly reduced the white space in the middle of the plot.

```
set.seed = 42
df <- data.frame(
  cat  = runif(10, 1, 20),
  mean = runif(10, 350, 450),
  ss   = runif(10, 1, 50))

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = cat, y = ss + 250),
           stat = "identity",
           fill = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = cat, y = mean)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = cat, y = mean),
              method = "loess", se = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~.-250,
                                         name  = "sample size")) +   
  labs(y = "mean") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

However, I don't love the really long bars for sample size, and I'd like to change the limits on the left y axis so that it starts 250 (where ss = 0).  Unfortunately, if I replace my current scale_y_continuous parameter with limits (see below), then the bars disappear.  How do I do this?

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = cat, y = ss + 250),
           stat = "identity",
           fill = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = cat, y = mean)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = cat, y = mean),
              method = "loess", se = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(250, 510),                         ### NEW Y AXIS LIMITS
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~.-250,
                                         name  = "sample size")) +   
  labs(y = "mean") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**EDIT: Updated plot with @AllanCameron's suggestion.**  This is really close, but it has the values of the bars extend below 0 on the secondary axis.

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = cat, y = ss + 250),
           stat = "identity",
           fill = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = cat, y = mean)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = cat, y = mean),
              method = "loess", se = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~.-250,
                                         name  = "sample size")) +   
  labs(y = "mean") +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(250, 510))  ### NEW
```

[image]

Comment: Try `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(250, 510))` instead of setting limits in your y scale.

Comment: Also note that many people consider bar plots that **don't** start at 0 to be  misleading. In the plot you have we can see at a glance that the increase from the first to the second bar is very small, just a few percent. If your axis starts at 250, at a glance it will look like a very large increase, maybe 50% or more.

Comment: @AllanCameron so close!  but the values extend below the 0 line a bit.  I'll update the question with a picture, since I can't put it in here.

Comment: @GregorThomas I have a secondary axis with the values of the bars, so that point isn't applicable in this situation.

Comment: Add `expand` = c(0,0) to the `scale_y_continuous()`.
I.e. 
`scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~.-250, name  = "sample size"), expand = c(0,0))`

Comment: People compare the lengths of bars. Visually, that's the difference between using bars and points. An axis label means that someone who looks closely at the graph will see the unusual choice you've made, but people who look quickly will not.

Comment: Don't take my word for it though, [here](http://stephanieevergreen.com/y-axis/) [are](https://flowingdata.com/2015/08/31/bar-chart-baselines-start-at-zero/) [a few](https://medium.com/loud-updates/what-happens-when-bar-charts-dont-start-with-zero-7db04221417e) [experts](https://www.storytellingwithdata.com/blog/2012/09/bar-charts-must-have-zero-baseline) [that](http://www.chadskelton.com/2018/06/bar-charts-should-always-start-at-zero.html) [agree](https://www.addtwodigital.com/add-two-blog/2021/9/26/rule-25-always-start-your-bar-charts-at-zero).

Comment: @GregorThomas I'm happy with my choice.

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez works perfectly!  Do you want to write up an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expand parameter in `scale_y_continuous()` to `c(0,0)`.
This tells ggplot2 to not add padding to the plot box.

```
  ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = cat, y = ss + 250),
           stat = "identity",
           fill = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = cat, y = mean)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = cat, y = mean),
              method = "loess", se = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~.-250, name  = "sample size"),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +   # New line here!
  labs(y = "mean") +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(250, 510))
```

[image]